# Trouble implementing tagging in a datomic db

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I'm trying to set up a tagging systems in my db, I have added two attrs to handle this:

```
{:db/ident            :metadata/tags
  :db/valueType        :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality      :db.cardinality/many
  :db/isComponent      true}
 {:db/ident            :metadata/tag
  :db/valueType        :db.type/keyword
  :db/cardinality      :db.cardinality/one
  :db/index            true}
```

This works more or less in terms of assigning tags, but how I am encountering some problems in filtering for tags. I think when doing this I assumed that I'd be able to reference the tags the way one would idents, as a keyword, e.g. `:tag1`. But it's proving a bit more challenging.

My first approach has been to use a query filter expression, something like this (non-working attempt):

```
'[:find (pull ?doc [*])
        :in $ ?tags
        :where [?doc :arb/metadata ?meta]
               [?doc :metadata/tags ?tagset]
               [(every? (set ?tags) ?tagset)]]
```

where :tags is a supplied list of tag keywords, e.g. `[:tag1 :tag2 ...]`. But the result of the pull doesn't quite work here because for each tag the pull returns a map including the `:db/id` as well as the tag e.g.:

```
[#:arb{:metadata
    [{:db/id 17592186045497,
      :metadata/tags
      [{:db/id 17592186045498, :metadata/tag :tag1}
       {:db/id 17592186045499, :metadata/tag :tag2}],
```

I thought that I could still work with this by mapping over the `?tagset` to extract just the tag keywords, but inside the map expression '?tagset` ends up being out of scope. So I'm a bit stumped about how I should approach this problem, which I feel must be somewhat common... Any tips?